# Can not update data in MongoDB Springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

My MongoDB Schema look like this. I want to update quantity field using uname, prodname and quantity. I tried to write a function in CartService class but it shows error
"The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Cart,String> is not applicable for the arguments (Optional)
] with root cause"

Please suggest any other solution or point out my mistake in code.

```
"Id":"string",
"uname":"string",
"products":[
  {
    "prodname":"string",
    "quantity":"int",
    "price":"double"
  }],
"tot_amt":"double",
}
```

This is one of my model Cart.java

```
public class Cart {
    
    @Id
    public String Id;
    
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    public String uname;
    
    public List<Product>products;
    public double tot_amt;

}
```

This is another model class Product.java

```
public class Product {

    public String prodname;
    public int quantity;
    public double price;
}
```

This is the repository interface CartRepository.java

```
public interface CartRepository extends MongoRepository<Cart,String>{
    
    @Query("{uname:?0}")
    Optional<Cart> findByName(String name);

}
```

This is Service class

```
public class CartService {
    
       @Autowired
       public CartRepository cartRepo;
       
       public MongoTemplate mt;
       
    
    public void saveUser(Cart cart) {
        List<Double>amt= new ArrayList<>();
        List<Product>products=cart.getProducts();
        products.forEach(p -> {
            double price=p.getPrice();
            int quantity=p.getQuantity();
            amt.add(price*quantity);
            
            
        });
         double tot_amount = 0;
            for (Double i : amt)
                tot_amount += i;
            
            cart.setTot_amt(tot_amount);
        
       cartRepo.save(cart);        
    }
     
    public List<Cart> getdata()
    {
        return cartRepo.findAll();
        
    }

    public Optional<Cart> getDetailsByName(String name) {
        
        Optional<Cart> savedCartData=Optional.of(cartRepo.findByName(name).orElseThrow(()->new RuntimeException(String.format("Not found %s",name))));
        return savedCartData;
         
    }

    public void updateProd(String name, String prodname, int qty) {
        
        Optional<Cart> cart=cartRepo.findByName(name);
        Cart c=cart.get();
        List<Product>products=c.getProducts();
        for(Product p:products)
        {
            if (p.getProdname().equals(prodname)) {
                p.setQuantity(qty);
                break;
                
            }
        }
        c.setProducts(products);
        cart=Optional.of(c);
        cartRepo.save(cart);
    }
```

And this is update function in controller class

```
@PutMapping("/{name}/{prodname}/{qty}")
    public String updateProduct(@PathVariable String name,@PathVariable String prodname,@PathVariable 
        int qty)
    {
        
            cartService.updateProd(name,prodname,qty);
            return "Product updated";
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me give you steps to achieve this, I won’t take the fun of coding away from you.

1. Get the cart using username (you already have the repository function for this)
2. Stream the products in the cart
3. filter the product which has the input product name.
4. Update the quantity in above stream (using peek) with the input quantity
5. Collect the product list from stream.
6. set the collected product list back to cart.
7. Save the cart save()

Comment: Thank You! I wrote this function-> public void updateProd(String name, String prodname, int qty) {
  
  Optional<Cart> cart=cartRepo.findByName(name);
  Cart c=cart.get();
  List<Product>products=c.getProducts();
  for(Product p:products)
  {
   if (p.getProdname().equals(prodname)) {
    p.setQuantity(qty);
    break;
    
   }
  }
  c.setProducts(products);
  cart=Optional.of(c);
  cartRepo.save(cart);
 }EOF! I am getting error->The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Cart,String> is not applicable for the arguments (Optional<Cart>)

Comment: Hi I configured it but one problem that I'm getting is in my database apart from Id field, one more filed id is showing and I don't know how

Comment: Are u referring to ObjectId?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field